# How to split a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
nested_dict={4.0: {'high': 93.34, 'low': 91.53},
 7.0: {'high': 13.95, 'low': 13.88},
 9.0: {'high': 48.84, 'low': 48.36}}  # ...continues
```

In the interest of full disclosure I want to map this dict to the index of a data frame, creating 2 new cols: 'high', and 'low'. After multiple attempts to map the nested dict to the index failed, the easiest solution seems to be to break the dict into 2, because that can easily be mapped:

```
high_dict={4.0:93.34, 7.0:13.95, 9.0: 48.84} # ...continues
low_dict ={4.0:91.53, 7.0:13.88, 9.0: 48.36} # ditto
```

The rest is easy:

```
df['high']= df.index.map(high_dict)
df['low'] = df.index.map(low_dict)
```

How do I split the above-nested dict into my desired 2 new dicts?

Comment: Not sure what you mean Rodrigo - works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-dictionary-comprehension) to achieve it in a pandas-independent way:

```
high_dict={key : value['high'] for key, value in nested_dict.items()}
low_dict ={key : value['low'] for key, value in nested_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this way:

```
nested_dict={4.0: {'high': 93.34, 'low': 91.53},
 7.0: {'high': 13.95, 'low': 13.88},
 9.0: {'high': 48.84, 'low': 48.36}}

high_dict = {}
low_dict = {}

for k, v in nested_dict.items():
    high_dict[k] = v['high']

for k, v in nested_dict.items():
    low_dict[k] = v['low']
    
print(high_dict)
print(low_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, you can just use a transposition:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict, orient='index').to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'high': {4.0: 93.34, 7.0: 13.95, 9.0: 48.84},
 'low': {4.0: 91.53, 7.0: 13.88, 9.0: 48.36}}
```

If you need variables:

```
high_dict = out['high']
low_dict  = out['low']
```

For a pure python solution with a single loop over the input dictionary:

```
high_dict = {}
low_dict = {}
mapper = {'high': high_dict, 'low': low_dict}

for key, d in nested_dict.items():
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in mapper:
            mapper[k][key] = v

high_dict
# {4.0: 93.34, 7.0: 13.95, 9.0: 48.84}

low_dict
# {4.0: 91.53, 7.0: 13.88, 9.0: 48.36}
```

Comment: An interesting way to turn a nested dict into a df. For my application I dont even do the interim step in python but just map pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict, orient='index') directly via merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nested_dict).transpose().reset_index(names="key")

high = df.set_index("key")["high"].to_dict()
low = df.set_index("key")["low"].to_dict()
```